# CRUD permissions

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

My database has four booleans:
allow_read
allow_create
allow_update
allow_delete

When a user logs on, I grab these and stick them in an array.

What is a good way to store these, so I can quickly check them without iterating through an array ? I was thinking maybe something like the way that Linux uses octal.

Mick

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are in a separate db (used by several applications), so I only get them on login (and stick them in the session).

I'm thinking of using 8,4,2,1 a bit like Linux uses 4,2,1